# MacBook Pro stopped working, won't turn on, MagSafe adapter blinking green

Tags: macbook-pro, magsafe

I was working on MacBook Pro (2012), the battery was full and the MagSafe adapter light was green.

When I connected an iPhone USB cable, the MacBook Pro immediately went black (it shut off without shutdown process), and the MagSafe light won't light up.

After I did the SMC reset, the computer won't turn on, the MagSafe light would be green and blinking for a minute, and then disappear again.

What can be done?

Answer (score 3):

I took it to the lab, there they unplugged the battery and plugged it back. That solved the problem.